# Валидность RSS: исправить ошибку

Tags: валидация, rss

Суть в чём, есть сайт на DLE, новости. Есть группа в контакте. Хочу подключить напрямую трансляцию из RSS в группу.

В поддержке контакта написали, что моя лента невлидна, и сначала нужно ее исправить. 
Исправил почти все ошибки. Но осталась одна.
В последней строке ленты.
http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffreelife.cv.ua%2Frss.php

Кто может подсказать как ее исправить? символы проверил, пробелов лишних нигде нету... все теги закрыты...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неправильно закрыт **CDATA**

У вас:

```
<description><![CDATA[ ... ]]</description>
```

Надо:

```
<description><![CDATA[ ... ]]></description>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, а я не заметил, несколько часво на последнюю строку смотрю и не могу пнять в чем там проблема )))